# Issue in displaying loader gif via Ajax

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax

I have a below section which is implemented to display loader gif associated to the update panel

```
  <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
 <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updPnlPromotion">
    <ProgressTemplate>
                <img alt="" src="Image/Ajaxloader.gif" />
    </ProgressTemplate>
 </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

This is the update panel which contains the dropdown which is a data bound control binded on the radio button checked changed event, but rather than partial postback and the display of loader gif, the entire page posts back.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlPromotion"  runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
              <ContentTemplate>
                <td align="left" style="width: 20%;background-color:#CDCD9C">
                    <asp:radiobutton ID="rdbPromotion" runat="server" Text="New Promotion" AutoPostBack="true" GroupName="TacPlan" OnCheckedChanged="rdbPromotion_OnCheckedChanged"  style="font-weight:bold" />
                </td>
                <td align="left" style="width:30%; vertical-align:middle; background-color:#EBEBEB; text-align:center">
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlPromotion" Width="95%"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label Text="*" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false" runat="server" ID="lblPromoPlanMandatory"></asp:Label>
                </td>
               </ContentTemplate>
               <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rdbPromotion" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
               </Triggers>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's an issue with the code you've posted.  I created a new ASPX page and copied your code into it.  It works as expected (I added a counter to monitor load events):

[image: animation of page behavior]

Here's the code behind I used for testing this:

```
Public Sub rdbPromotion_OnCheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rdbPromotion.CheckedChanged
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
End Sub

Private Sub Default5_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.counter.Text = Integer.Parse(Me.counter.Text) + 1
End Sub
```

Seems like a longshot, but maybe the browser you're testing with doesn't support partial rendering, or ASP.NET doesn't think that it does?:

http://ajax.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/mref/P_System_Web_UI_ScriptManager_EnablePartialRendering.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response but that didnt work for me. I tried your solution but I cant see the loader gif appearing.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a new page, adding just the code in question, and veryfing that it works in that minimal state.  If it does, you can gradually bring in the rest of your code.  That'll help you isolate what's causing it to not work.  I don't have any ideas of what that could be though.

Comment: Ben..I used the developer tools to figure out whats wrong..I was getting exception at this line if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.'); after I googled the solution , I added the handler to include scriptresource.axd in web.config. The exception got resolved but its still not partially posting back and no image appeared. Also this is how the update progress is being rendered in the IE 11 browser< div id="UpdateProgress1" style="display:none;">
                     <img alt="" src="Image/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </div>

Comment: Interesting.  What version of .NET are you using?  I created a simple .NET 4.5 project.  You could see if that works on your machine. https://github.com/OsborneSupremacy/AjaxTroubleshoot

Comment: my project is developed in .Net 4.0. Its strange that somehow its not working in the solution in which I intend to ajaxify pages because when I created a new project with this code it runs perfectly. I wonder what could be striving that is ignoring Ajax and run controls with post backs. I also replaced the new projects web.config but it doesn't change the behavior in the other solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to my problem, upon reviewing the web.config file I found the weird setting xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" there which was basically stopping the page to ajaxify somehow, by removing it, it works as expected.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out!